# Generate a checkerboard pattern of a particular size when printed

Tags: matlab, printing

I was trying to generate a checkerboard pattern in MATLAB in such a way that when it is printed on a US letter sized paper, the width of each box will be 30 mm.

I tried to change various properties of `gcf` such as `'Units'` and `'PaperSize'` etc, but the PDF doesn't print as desired.

I came across several other online methods to generate what I need, but I would like to generate one in MATLAB.  Any ideas? Below is sample code.

```
width = 30;
I = checkerboard(width,5,4);
I = I>0.5;
imshow(I);
saveas(gcf,'checkerboard.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab can only generate the width based on pixel since Matlab doesn't know the physical dimensions of your screen.

One way is to find the **Pixel Per Inch (PPI)** of your screen. Here is a [website](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/pixels-per-inch#using-the-pixels-per-inch-calculator-an-example) to calculate the PPI by screen dimension and resolution. Then we can calculate the `width` (the pixel for 30mm) = PPI * 1.1811. (1.1811 inch is equal to 30 mm )

Example, for a screen of PPI = 220 (15.4 in, 2880 * 1800), `width=220*1.1811=260`.

Answer (score 0):

There are figure properties that start with `'Paper'` that specify the size and location of the figure on paper when printed (to PDF or to printer). [Here is a list of all figure properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html). You'll find these properties under the heading "Printing and Exporting" (see the table on contents on the left pane).

We can use these properties as follows. Note that we don't care about the size of the figure on the screen, so we leave it to the default size. What we do is set the `'PaperPosition'` property so that the figure has a certain size when printed. We then create a drawing of a checkerboard pattern that fills the figure. The drawing will thus have the size of the figure itself when printed.

Note how we set the `'PaperSize'` property in inches (8.5" x 11" is US Letter), but the `'PaperPosition'` property in centimeters (so that we can easily figure out the 3x3 cm squares to draw).

The drawing itself could probably be simplified, but this works. It is much more efficient to draw the pattern using patches (i.e. create a vector drawing) than using an image (i.e. the `checkerboard` function in OP) when printing to PDF. The output is prettier and the file is smaller. But the same could be done displaying an image.

```
% Grid size (number of squares)
m = 6; n = 8;
% Square size (in centimeters)
side = 3;
% Create figure and set sizes for printing
figh = figure;
set(figh,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperSize',[8.5 11]);
set(figh,'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperPosition',[1,1,side*m,side*n]);
% Create axes that fill the figure
axh = axes('Parent',figh,'Units','normalized','Position',[0,0,1,1]);
set(axh,'Color',[1,1,1])
set(axh.XAxis,'Visible','off');
set(axh.YAxis,'Visible','off');
% Draw rectangles
set(axh,'XLim',[0,m],'YLim',[0,n]);
for ii=0:m
   for jj=0:n
      if mod(ii+jj,2)==0
         rectangle('Position',[ii,jj,1,1],'FaceColor',[0,0,0],'LineStyle','none');
      end
   end
end
% Print to PDF
print(figh,'-dpdf','checkerboard.pdf')
```